# Call APOC procedure in a subquery

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I am trying to set labels dynamically with the `apoc.create.setLabels` function:

```
:auto MATCH (n:TempNode)
CALL {
    with n
    CALL apoc.create.setLabels( n, [ n.type ] ) YIELD node
} IN TRANSACTIONS;
```

I get a strange error that I never saw before:

**Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError**

```
Variable `n` not defined (line 3, column 10 (offset: 35))
"    with n"
          ^
```

Any ideas why this fairly simple query does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cypher queries require that they should end either with `RETURN` or with some write operation, using `MERGE`, `SET` etc.

Both of your inner and outer queries return nothing, so try returning something like this:

```
:auto MATCH (n:TempNode)
CALL {
    with n
    CALL apoc.create.setLabels( n, [ n.type ] ) YIELD node
    RETURN node
} IN TRANSACTIONS
RETURN node;
```

Comment: Thanks, adding a simple `RETURN 1` for both procedure calls works. I think you actually have to add a return to both calls.

Comment: yess, both should return